# Write CSV then Save or Edit

Tags: c#, csv

I have a problem. I'm creating a CSV in runtime, then giving the user the ability to save it or open it, but it does not do anything to me, what am I doing wrong? Can someone help me?

```
public void WriteToCSV(List<mifid2_vpc_monitored_detail_view> list, string filename)
    {
        string attachment = "attachment; filename=" + filename;

        HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "public");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;


        WriteHeader();
        StringBuilder csv = new StringBuilder();

        string _uti, _counterparty;
        DateTime _maturity, _date;
        decimal _volume;

        var newLine = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        {
            if (list[i].uti_cd == null) _uti = "-"; else _uti = list[i].uti_cd;
            if (list[i].namecounterparty == null) _counterparty = "-"; else _counterparty = list[i].namecounterparty;
            if (list[i].maturity == null) _maturity = DateTime.MinValue.Date; else _maturity = list[i].maturity;
            if (list[i].contract_volume == 0) _volume = 0; else _volume = list[i].contract_volume;
            if (list[i].evaluation_date == null) _date = DateTime.MinValue.Date; else _date = list[i].evaluation_date;

            newLine = string.Format("{0},{1},{2},{3},{4}", _uti, _counterparty, _maturity, _volume, _date);
            csv.AppendLine(newLine);
        }

        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(csv.ToString());
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
    }

    private void WriteHeader()
    {
        string columnNames = "UTI code, Counterparty, Maturity, Volume, Evaluation Date";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(columnNames);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(Environment.NewLine);
    }
```

Comment: Open the navigator debugger and look at the response content, there you may get more info.

Comment: Download initiated by an 'XMLHttpRequest', when the 'send()' method is invoked

This download occurred during the processing of the document.

Into response body:
UTI code, Counterparty, Maturity, Volume, Evaluation Date ecc ecc ecc

Comment: Rather than StringBuilder, save RAM and start pushing results to your users faster by writing directly to the Response stream.

Comment: Also: what does `WriteHeader()` look like?

Comment: Don't roll your own CSV writing logic. You're re-inventing the wheel. You're going to have messy code that doesn't respect the rules of CSV files. Instead, use a library that solves these problems for you, such as [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/).

Comment: You are calling to this code from an AJAX request, that's why there's no message to the user. Start it through a link and it will work.

Comment: I can not use external libraries

Answer (score 0):

Code works fine for me. But browser downloads file without extension.

Does `filename` contains file extension?

If not, try this

```
string attachment = "attachment; filename=" + filename + ".csv";
```

Answer (score 0):

I still do not understand where the problem may be, I tried different solutions, then I found an example on the web that works through a demo, but that once I implement it, it does not work, it could be that I work with sharepoint 2013 and that the button that refers to the export is in a webpart?

Code:

```
HttpResponse Response = HttpContext.Current.Response;

string csv = string.Empty;
csv += "UTI code, Counterparty, Maturity, Volume, Evaluation Date";
csv += "\r\n";

string _uti, _counterparty;
DateTime _maturity, _date;
decimal _volume;

for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        {
            if (list[i].uti_cd == null) _uti = "-"; else _uti = list[i].uti_cd;
            if (list[i].namecounterparty == null) _counterparty = "-"; else _counterparty = list[i].namecounterparty;
            if (list[i].maturity == null) _maturity = DateTime.MinValue.Date; else _maturity = list[i].maturity;
            if (list[i].contract_volume == 0) _volume = 0; else _volume = list[i].contract_volume;
            if (list[i].evaluation_date == null) _date = DateTime.MinValue.Date; else _date = list[i].evaluation_date;
            csv += _uti + ",";
            csv += _counterparty + ",";
            csv += _maturity + ",";
            csv += _volume + ",";
            csv += _date;
            csv += "\r\n";
        }

        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=SqlExport.csv");
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.ContentType = "application/text";
        Response.Output.Write(csv);
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
```

Answer (score -2):

This should help:

```
public void WriteToCSV(List<mifid2_vpc_monitored_detail_view> list, string filename)
    {
    string attachment = "attachment; filename=" + filename;

    HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "public");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;


    WriteHeader();
    StringBuilder csv = new StringBuilder();

    string _uti, _counterparty;
    DateTime _maturity, _date;
    decimal _volume;

    var newLine = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
    {
        if (list[i].uti_cd == null) _uti = "-"; else _uti = list[i].uti_cd;
        if (list[i].namecounterparty == null) _counterparty = "-"; else _counterparty = list[i].namecounterparty;
        if (list[i].maturity == null) _maturity = DateTime.MinValue.Date; else _maturity = list[i].maturity;
        if (list[i].contract_volume == 0) _volume = 0; else _volume = list[i].contract_volume;
        if (list[i].evaluation_date == null) _date = DateTime.MinValue.Date; else _date = list[i].evaluation_date;

        newLine = string.Format("{0},{1},{2},{3},{4}", _uti, _counterparty, _maturity, _volume, _date);
        csv.AppendLine(newLine);
    }


    MemoryStream mstream = new MemoryStream();
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(mstream);
    sw.Write(csv);
    sw.Flush();
    sw.Close();
    byte[] byteArray = mstream.ToArray();
    mstream.Flush();
    mstream.Close();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(byteArray);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
}
```

Comment: Please flesh out your answer. Don’t just provide code please. Explain to the user. Teach them the principles of what they need to do.

Comment: The code is self explanatory, I have changed the way it writes the data to the `Response`, instead of using `Response.Write` I use a `MemoryStream`, load the content to `byte[]` array and write all as a Binary

Comment: @AMINCHAR A giant code dump is the opposite of self explanatory. Always give an explanation of what you changed and why.